# Oracle query on TCURR

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

This is Oracle Query in my application.

I think this is used for currency conversion.When I run this query its throwing an error message

> An error occurred while attempting a database operation: 
>   Error Executing Database Query.

Can I know where i need to change to this query?

**Query**

```
SELECT count(*) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT kurst AS look_up_mode_cd,
         fcurr AS source_currency_cd,
         tcurr AS target_currency_cd,
         substr(to_char(99999999 - gdatu),1,4) AS effective_date_yr,
         substr(to_char(99999999 - gdatu),5,2) AS effective_date_mnth,
         (ukurs*tfact / ffact) AS multiplier_rate_amt,
         to_number(to_char((1 /(ukurs*tfact / ffact)),9999999.9999999)) AS divisor_rate_amt
  FROM tcurr
  WHERE kurst = '001E'
    AND substr(to_char(99999999 - gdatu), 1, 4) = '2016'
    AND substr(to_char(99999999 - gdatu), 5, 2) = '4'
    AND tcurr = 'USD'
  UNION
  SELECT kurst AS look_up_mode_cd,
         tcurr AS target_currency_cd,
         fcurr AS source_currency_cd,
         substr(to_char(99999999 - gdatu),1,4) AS effective_date_yr,
         substr(to_char(99999999 - gdatu),5,2) AS effective_date_mnth,
         (-1 *ukurs*tfact / ffact) AS multiplier_rate_amt,
         to_number(to_char((-1*1 /(ukurs*tfact / ffact)),9999999.9999999)) AS divisor_rate_amt
  FROM tcurr
  WHERE kurst = 'EURE'
    AND substr(to_char(99999999 - gdatu), 1, 4) = '2016'
    AND substr(to_char(99999999 - gdatu), 5, 2) = '4'
    AND tcurr = 'EUR'
    AND fcurr = 'USD'
)
```

Comment: Does it execute when you execute it from Oracle SQL Developer or SQL Plus. Does it throw any ORA errors?

Answer (score 1):

`to_number(to_char((-1*1 /(ukurs*tfact / ffact)),9999999.9999999))` does not make any sense. Why are you converting a number to a string, just to convert it back to a number again?

But the problem is you are calling it incorrectly. The second parameter for `to_char()` needs to be a string, not a number. So you need `'9999999.9999999'`

But the whole expression can be simplified to:

```
-1/(ukurs*tfact / ffact)
```

No need to convert it back and forth.

---

Unrelated, but:

This: `substr(to_char(99999999 - gdatu), 1, 4)` is **highly** suspicious as well. What exactly are you storing in `gdatu` that you need to subtract that from 99999999 to get something like a date? Why don't you store dates in a proper `DATE` column?

Comment: Actually its having the parameters in place of '2016' . I kept parameter actual value there.

Comment: @KarthikSharma:  The `'2016'` isn't the problem. The `substr(to_char(99999999 - gdatu), 1, 4)` is